# What does "twittering away to itself" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "twittering away to itself" mean? Does it mean that the radio is twittering and the sound generated by the radio is outward from it?

> White hair endows you with the demeanour of a friendly witch. Our geriatric radio – a wedding-present from my brother – is **twittering away** to itself. I’m about to knock on the glass, but your laptop screen glows into life: and suddenly here’s our son’s hazy face, bringing you news from across the ocean.

(Excerpted from David Mitchell's novel *The Gardener*.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I perceive it, the sentence means that the radio is emitting sounds (*twittering away*), but nobody is actually or really listening to it, so that the radio *twitters away **to itself***, instead of doing it for other people.

Comment: can it imply the radio have fun for itself?

Comment: @GodelSaint. According to the OALD, the verb "to twitter" means *to talk quickly in a high excited voice, especially about something that is not very important*; "having fun" is not implied, even though you wouldn't use this verb if you were to communicate something very serious or tragic.

Comment: in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary[http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twitter?q=to+twitter], there is no explaintions about **"twitter away to"**, but as you said before, the radio twitters to itself , so actually we can imagine the radio have fun for itself like a human being.